# My mother refuses to believe I have Social Anxiety Disorder

Tags: anxiety

So, basically, I have Social Anxiety. I have taken many tests, and have been told by my doctor that I do. She even recommended a therapist to me. I am a freshman in high school, so it's a bit stressful, which adds on to the general anxiety I have as well. I've told my mom this many times and she even looked up what Social Anxiety was, and I had all symptoms. But even after all this, she refuses to admit that I have it and refuses to take me to my  recommended therapist. I somewhat feel as if she doesn't want to believe I do because my older brother, who is 31 has ADHD, and my older sister, who is around 28-29, is bipolar. But I want her to realize that I do have this mental disorder and I need someone to talk to, instead of the getting to same response of, "Get over it" or "You're just being dramatic". I also want her to know this because she always says that we "Never have time" to go to a therapist, but my stepfather has a very short work schedule, so he could always take me.

Any thoughts.?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Parenting SE. Have you talked to your stepfather? Alternatively could you talk to the therapist by phone or Zoom or something? Could the issue be financial (I gather you are in the US)? Also, could your older siblings help at all?

Answer (score 5):

### Facilitate a conversation between your mother and your doctor

There is no argument you can make that will convince your mother if she will not listen to the arguments in the first place.  Your arguments are far more likely to be successful if they come from someone your mother respects and looks to as an authority.

There are a number of possible candidates for the role of your intermediary, but your doctor is likely your best choice.  Their title gives them authority, you already know they will support your side, and they likely have experience convincing unwilling parents to listen to them.

Other possible candidates might possibly include (in order of plausibility) your step-father, grandparents, and older siblings, depending on your family's relationships, but I don't know enough about those to judge.  Your doctor is most likely your best bet.